# Cannot play Blu-Ray discs with VLC, Getting the error 'BD+ decoding library does not work'

Tags: vlc, blu-ray

When I put the disc in the tray and try to play with VLC I get this error,

"Blu-ray error: Your system BD+ decoding library does not work. Missing configuration? Your input can't be opened: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'bluray:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details."

I installed MakeMKV and tried this,

1. Insert Blu-Ray Movie
2. Launch VLC
3. CTRL+D to enter Disc Menu
4. Select Blu-Ray Option and check: No Menu option.
5. Under drive select browse and highlight your drive only on the left side (not the 3 folders on the right)
6. Select Play from the former "Open Media" screen. (I couldn't find Play from the former "Open Media" screen. This might be what I am missing.)

Please help and thank you much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The answer could be a little late, but may be helpful for other ones.
I found it at https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=170068. I had the same problem, so I just tried it successfully.

You need the file https://forum.doom9.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=13985&d=1390515451. It is called your missing "configuration", but is in fact a set of keys.
Places the files from the zip file in the `~/.config/bdplus/vm0` folder. Create if it is not there. (`~` is your home path.)

Terminal solution:

```
wget -O /tmp/vm0.zip 'https://forum.doom9.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=13985&d=1390515451'
mkdir -p ~/.config/bdplus
unzip /tmp/vm0.zip -d ~/.config/bdplus
```

Comment: Tried this on 18.04 with no luck.

Comment: Could you give more details?

Comment: the given vm0 zip file works fine, but it's very old and doesn't work for newer discs.